# What is the earliest version of Tensorflow that contains Tensorflow Lite?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm wondering when exactly Tensorflow Lite was first introduced into the Tensorflow source code? What was the first Tensorflow release date / version that contained TFLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Looking at the past releases, I see that tensorflow lite was made an official module in 1.13.1 2019 version. Here is what is stated: TensorFlow Lite Move from tensorflow/contrib/lite to tensorflow/lite

Old Answer: The details of when it was released are in this article: https://venturebeat.com/2019/03/06/google-launches-tensorflow-lite-1-0-for-mobile-and-embeddable-devices/.

It was introduced in 2019, but was demoed earlier in May 2017. The earliest version is Tensorflow Lite 1.0.

Comment: My understanding is that TFLite is a module inside the standard Tensorflow source code - I don't think it has its own version number. Hence my question about which version of Tensorflow first contained the "lite" module / subfolder

Comment: @JeremiahRose Looking at the past releases, I see that tensorflow lite was made an official module in `1.13.1` 2019 version. Here is what is stated: 

TensorFlow Lite
Move from tensorflow/contrib/lite to tensorflow/lite

Comment: Thanks Ayush! If you add this to your answer I will accept it :)

Comment: @JeremiahRose No problem. Have added it.